# subprocess choose between stdout and os.devnull

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

For a project I would like to write a code that I want to reuse in various part of my project. I need to execute a command and want to be able to choose between printing in the console or muting the command.
I have came up with that, but I am not sure if it is okay and if the "with" works correctly this way:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

def run_subprocess(cmd, display_output : bool=False):
    if display_output:
        stdout = sys.stdout
    else:
        stdout = open(os.devnull, "w")
        
    with stdout as s:
        exit_code = subprocess.call([cmd], shell=True, stdout=s)
    return exit_code
```

Is it ok to do this way ? Should I change something ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sentinel [`subprocess.DEVNULL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL) for /dev/null or the default `None` for stdout instead:

```py
import subprocess

def run_subprocess(cmd, display_output: bool = False):
    stdout = None if display_output else subprocess.DEVNULL
    return subprocess.call([cmd], shell=True, stdout=stdout)
```

Using these makes `subprocess` handle both targets properly and in a system-independent way.

Comment: It seems to work perfectly! So much more elegant :) Thanks !

(no need for sys and os anymore, also 'if' instead of 'of' in the function)

Comment: @th0mash Thanks for pointing out the typos and dead code, removed both.

Answer (score 0):

I found something way cleaner that I am using, still not sure if it is 'good practice' but it seems to be quite okay for my application

```
import os
import subprocess

def run_subprocess(cmd, display_output: bool = False):
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as s:
        args = {'stdout': s} if display_output else {}
        exit_code = subprocess.call([cmd], shell=True, **args)
    return exit_code
```